# Moving certain data to a new data set

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to move specific words from one data set to another in R. I have used the below code:

```
treatmentWords <- select(filter(m4, m4$word == 'CHLOROQUINE'),c(index,word))
```

But this returns an empty data set. The complete data set is currently in m4 with and index and word column. Basically I want the data set that looks like this

```
m4
Index   Word
1       CHLOROQUINE
2       SHOT
3       CHLOROQUINE
4       SHOT
```

to use a filter or select command to now have the below in treatmentWords:

```
treatmentWords
Index   Word
1       CHLOROQUINE
3       CHLOROQUINE
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred method is:

```
m4[m4$Word == "CHLOROQUINE",]
  Index        Word
1     1 CHLOROQUINE
3     3 CHLOROQUINE
```

Another popular method from Base R is `subset`. It takes less typing usually:

```
subset(m4, Word == "CHLOROQUINE")
  Index        Word
1     1 CHLOROQUINE
3     3 CHLOROQUINE
```

But I see you are also using `filter`, which usually comes from `dplyr`. So you could do this:

```
library(dplyr)
m4 %>% 
  filter(Word == "CHLOROQUINE")
  Index        Word
1     1 CHLOROQUINE
2     3 CHLOROQUINE
```

If you want to assign the results to `treatmentWords`:

```
treatmentWords <- m4[m4$Word == "CHLOROQUINE",]
```